# Any relation between Kernel methods and Variational methods?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, definition

I am familiar with kernel method, which is defined in the link:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method

On the other hand I am familiar with variational methods which is defined in the link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_principle

It appears to me variational method  relates to finding a appropriate function using the variational principle and RKHS is also a technique to find a appropriate function based on a inner product distance.

My question: is there link between them or they are quite different methods?